# RestSharp - How to send multipart/form-data body request without uploading a file?

Tags: c#, rest, multipartform-data, restsharp

I am unable to send a rest request using RestSharp where the body is encoded as multipart/form-data. How would you do this via RestSharp? Below is my current code:

```
string url = NDRoutes.Document;
        Boolean useXml = false;

        NewPaperDocumentRequest paperDocumentEntity = FillPaperDocumentRequest(createPaperDocumentRequest);
        RestRequest rr = _communicationsService.FormRequest(Method.POST, url, useXml);

        rr.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
        string body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paperDocumentEntity);
        rr.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        rr.AlwaysMultipartFormData = true;

        rr.AddParameter("action", paperDocumentEntity.Action, "multipart/form-data", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        rr.AddParameter("name", paperDocumentEntity.Name, "multipart/form-data", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        rr.AddParameter("extension", paperDocumentEntity.Extension, "multipart/form-data", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        rr.AddParameter("cabinet", paperDocumentEntity.Cabinet, "multipart/form-data", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        rr.AddParameter("failOnError", paperDocumentEntity.FailOnError, "multipart/form-data", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        rr.AddParameter("return", paperDocumentEntity.Return, "multipart/form-data", ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        rr.AddBody(body);

        _communicationsService.ExecuteRequest(rr);
```

Comment: Why are you adding `multipart/form-data` parameters and calling `AddBody()` with JSON? Shouldn't you do one or the other?

Comment: Seems like I am using it incorrectly. I am unable to find an example where I can send a multipart/form-data request with data from a class I have created in C#. So an example on the usage as a multipart will be helpful!

Comment: What you have there is almost correct but what you need to do is to remove the rr.AddBody(body) and all the other parameters and add rr.AddObject(paperDocumentEntity). This will add the properties with values that exist in paperDocumentEntity for you.